# POST request error with github API

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, github-api

I'm getting a "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. How am i supposed to used the API ? I get the code but the POST request for the token fails

```
var gist = {

clientId: 'clientId',
clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
authUrl: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
tokenUrl: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',

getCode: function() {
    var url = gist.authUrl+'?client_id='+gist.clientId;
    location.href = url;
},
processCode: function() {
    var code = location.search.slice(6);
    var url = gist.tokenUrl;
    $.post(gist.tokenUrl, {
        client_id : gist.clientId,
        client_secret : gist.clientSecret,
        code : code
    }, function(){
        console.log("POST request sent");
    })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.error("POST request error");
        })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing

```
Any domain that is registered as an OAuth Application is accepted.
```

To register you application go to: https://github.com/settings/applications

You need to be posting from the same domain that your application is registered on. If you are trying to test locally you may need to modify your hosts file and run your server on port 80.